# How to use brython to create an interactive python script writer

Tags: python, html, brython

I am trying to create a site which auto generates python code and is presented to the user in an ide style where they can edit it then run it live using brython.

I am having trouble setting up the ide part I found brython console but that won't work for editing things. So my question is are there any existing implementations I can use?

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460131/import-psaw-brython

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an extensible web IDE. An IDE that runs in the browser that expects you to build on top of, so that you can likely get the text out of it to provide to Brython. I'd try searching for terms like these:

`extensible web IDE`

`web IDE framework`

`IDE framework in JavaScript`

et c.